# aws-cli offers running "aws configure" despite the fact I have config

Tags: aws-cli

I get:

```
[vao@machine ~]$ aws s3 ls
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

despite the:

```
[vao@machine ~]$ ll .aws
total 8
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  44 Feb  6 16:09 config
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 116 Feb  6 16:09 credentials
```

So as you can see I already ran `aws configure` and have files created.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, If you specify profile other then default in credentials file, you **HAVE** to specify `--profile`, otherwise you get misleading warning:

```
[postgres@p5-prod-bert01 ~]$ aws s3 ls --profile backup
2016-06-09 12:46:14 config-bucket-024181976471
2016-11-21 10:30:21 bucket_one
2016-09-06 12:41:08 two-bucket
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make aws-cli work without providing a profile ( --profile)
you have to issue

`aws configure`

without specifying a profile.
By doing so, you configure the default profile that you aws-cli commands will run under.

If your aws-cli configurations have been done by specifying a profile (--profile) chances are that you do not have a default configuration thus specifying a profile is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you have mentioned above point to credential file not setup correctly.

Depending upon the number of profiles you have, credential file should look some thing like this:

## cat credentials

[default]

aws_access_key_id = xxxx

aws_secret_access_key = xxxx

[TestEnv]

aws_access_key_id = xxxx

aws_secret_access_key = xxxx

Reference URL:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/

Note: don't include blank lines in file.